# c# date time variable not updating

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a TimeNow variable which updates the current time and it was working fine but today i found out it is not updating the value

```
private static readonly DateTime _TimeNow= DateTime.UtcNow;
```

This is the variable but now TimeNow is not updating the value.

Comment: @Vishal why would static have anything to do with this

Comment: Do you expect it to be updating the value constantly as time changes? If so, get rid of _TimeNow and just use DateTime.UtcNow instead...

Comment: whats the point of giving negative to my question? i dont know about this and that is why i am here to clear my doubts as it was working before but not working now. If you dont like my question than dont answer it

Comment: @BrianDishaw that is what i am using now instead of declaring a variable but before it was working fine but now it is not so that is why i am confused

Comment: You need to also show the code that periodically sets a new value for `_TimeNow`, and also the process that causes that code to periodically execute. The code you've shown, by itself, will only do what you describe: set the value once, and only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted will only ever assign a value to the "_TimeNow" field once. It would be impossible for it to ever assign it again.

If you had some other place in the code where you were regularly assigning a new value to the field, then your program wouldn't compile because of the "readonly" attribute on the field.

What makes you think that the value of the field should ever change? The lack of such a detail in your question may well have something to do with the down-votes you've received so far.

Frankly, I question the value of such a field. At the very least, by the time any other part of the code reads the value, it won't have the correct value for "now" and so the field is named incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

You should refer `DateTime.UtcNow` each time, when you'd like to get current time.

Comment: that is what i am doing now but i asked this question because before it was working like this but now it its not and i wanted to know why it is not working now

Comment: What time is set to _TimeNow?

Answer (score 1):

The **readonly** keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, **assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class**.

Take the readonly away and try again.

Edit: Check this code;

```
Class TestClass{

    private static DateTime _TimeNow;
    private static Timer timer;

    public TestClass(){
       timer = new Timer();
       timer.Interval = 1000;
       _TimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow; //don't forget this is a variable and not a timer
       timer.Tick = new EventHalndler(timer_tick);
       timer.Start();
    }
    private void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
       _TimeNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
 }
```

Comment: Are you actually updating your variable in code anywhere? DateTime is NOT a timer or a clock. It's simply stores the numbers you give it when you initialize it. You need to update that variable all the time. I'll edit my post with some code in a sec.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
private static DateTime _TimeNow= DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Instead of:

```
private static readonly DateTime _TimeNow= DateTime.UtcNow;
```